# extracting text from pdf using python3

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pdfminer

I am trying to extract text from pdf file using `slate` module, as shown in this

```
$sudo pip install https://codeload.github.com/timClicks/slate/zip/master
Collecting https://codeload.github.com/timClicks/slate/zip/master
  Downloading https://codeload.github.com/timClicks/slate/zip/master
Requirement already satisfied: distribute in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from slate==0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pdfminer3k in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from slate==0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from distribute->slate==0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytest>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pdfminer3k->slate==0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ply>=3.4 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pdfminer3k->slate==0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.29 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=2.0->pdfminer3k->slate==0.5.2)
Installing collected packages: slate
  Found existing installation: slate 0.3
    Uninstalling slate-0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled slate-0.3
  Running setup.py install for slate ... done
Successfully installed slate-0.5.2
```

and I am trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import slate

with open('/var/tmp/PhysRevB.93.014203.pdf') as fp:
    doc = slate.PDF(fp)
print(len(doc))
print(doc[0])
```

which is giving me error:

```
$python3 tstslt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tstslt.py", line 2, in <module>
    import slate
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slate/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from .classes import PDF
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slate/classes.py", line 25, in <module>
    import utils
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

I can extract the text using `PyPDF2`, but looking if slate is better.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/timClicks/slate/issues/18) one of slate's dependecies (pdfminer) doesn't support Python3

> (...)
>
> The "pdfminer" that is required does not work because it is currently
>   incompatible with python 3.5.
>
> It says so on their readme:
>
> https://github.com/euske/pdfminer
>
> "Install Python 2.6 or newer. (Python 3 is not supported.)"

Comment: pdfminer.six is python3 version of pdfminer

pip install pdfminer.six


https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/

Answer (score 0):

[slate3k](https://pypi.org/project/slate3k/) is a fork of the original [slate](https://github.com/timClicks/slate) for python3.

you can install slate3k using `pip install slate3k`

Answer (score 0):

After You installed the **slate3k**,You also have to setup the mode, how to open the file:

```
#/usr/bin/python3
import slate

with open('/var/tmp/PhysRevB.93.014203.pdf', 'rb') as fp:
    doc = slate.PDF(fp)
print(len(doc))
print(doc[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just install `pip install utils` after you installed `pip install https://github.com/timClicks/slate/archive/master.zip`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32553575)